# Firestore's Entity Reads quota - what is included?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

On a very small test with Firestore I already ran out of my free daily quota. It is "entity reads quota" I seem to have exceeded.

This is just 50 000 entity reads, but I am still surprised. Exactly how is this counted?